# AngularJS $state.go() do not emit $stateChangeSuccess?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I have controller `A` and `B` residing in separate states.

When I invoke `$state.go('state_b');` Angular will change state to `state_b` and load controller `B`. All as expected. What is not expected is that I do not get `$stateChangeSuccess` in my `B` controller.

Why my `B` isn't getting that `$stateChangeSuccess` resulting from `$state.go` from controller `A`?

Is there any other way for `B` controller to know that its displayed? (It do not matter which previous state was active, just that state/controller `B` is active again)

State definitions:

```
.state("state_b", {
  url: "b/?:id",
  templateUrl:"/template/cms/shared/tabs/genericView.html.twig",
  reloadOnSearch: false,
  moduleName: "Module B",
  componentName: "Component B",
  parent: "application"
})
.state("state_a", {
  url: "a/",
  templateUrl: "/template/bundlename/a/index.html.twig",
  moduleName: "Module A",
  componentName: "Component A",
  parent: "application",
  controller: "OohAController as a",
  resolve: {
    b: function(OohBService, OohActiveBService) {
      var bId = OohActiveBService.getActiveB();
      return OohAService.get({id: bId}).$promise;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Could you show us your states config please?

Comment: There is no `B` controller

Comment: @Michael, cause `B` lives alongside `B''` and both are childs of controller which actually handle `state_b`. Complex. I think so too! Can't do a thing about it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say, that the concept is working. There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/YTAjGwzNvkqrwrXVTYGq?p=preview)

And this events will be fired

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(evt, to, params, from) {
      console.log("from : " + from.name + ", to:" + to.name);
    });
}])
```

on any transition like this

```
<a ui-sref="state_b({id:1})">
<a ui-sref="state_b({id:22})">
<a ui-sref="state_a">
```

The only important change I made is URL

```
  .state("state_b", {
      // url: "b/?:id",
      url: "/b/?:id",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  })
  .state("state_a", {
      //url: "a/",
      url: "/a/",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: 'OohAController as a',
  })
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YTAjGwzNvkqrwrXVTYGq?p=preview)

Comment: I think You have forgotten to write new urls in Your code snippet.

Comment: Sorry ;) ... fixed ;) and the link to plunker also targets the one with "fixed url" ... hope it helps a bit

Comment: Nope. For me adding `/` did not solved issue. In fact it made `/#/state_b/ `unaccessible. So I think my app is already configured so it do not need prefix `/` in state definitions.

Comment: Why did You use `$rootScope` to register listeners on `$stateChangeSuccess`? Simple `$scope` won't do?

Comment: Navigation to state b without id is not feasable. In that case, UI-Router will keep the last ID selected and WILL NOT re-trigger the state change. You should use some parent state for that. There is an updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/5mscK3YRJvnuefn9UpMY?p=preview

Comment: $scope could be used as well, but then it is just registered and de-registered on any controller creation and destruction.

Comment: $rootScope is a right place for eventing in this case. As I tried to explain, any other means - all the time adde listener and remove...